# jQuery keyup event gets missed

Tags: keyup, onkeyup

It seems like the keyup event on a textbox gets missed if you hit a key then immediately (I mean REALLY quickly) click in a different textbox.

I'm getting around this by trapping both the keyup and the blur events.  Is there a better way to do this?

The code to demonstrate this is...

```
Hit a key here: <input id="i1" /><br/>
Click mouse here: <input id="i2" />
<pre></pre>

$('#i1').bind('focus blur select change click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout keypress keydown keyup', function (e) {
    $pre = $('pre');
    $pre.html(e.type + ": " + $(this).val() + "<br>" + $pre.html());
});
```

[And here's a jfiddle that demonstrates it.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdahbour/0wf38ycz/)  Put the cursor in the first textbox, hover your mouse over the second textbox, then very quickly (almost simultaneously) click the mouse button in the second box.  You'll see the keydown, keypress, change, and blur, but not the keyup.

Comment: What should we do? Press a key while the first textbox has focus, then release the key immediately before clicking the second textbox?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Put the focus in the first textbox.  Press and release a key then click in the second textbox.  It has to be done quickly.  Like the key release and the mouse click have to happen almost simultaneously.  That seems to cause the keyup event in the first textbox to be lost.